# Problema al eliminar espacios de una columna de un dataframe en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ocupar el método `.replace()` no elimina espacios, y con `.str.strip()` me elimina los espacios que necesito pero también elimina el resto de la información de la columna entera. Intenté agregando `regex=True` y tampoco.  Ocupo *PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)* y también intenté con *Jupyter Notebook* y tampoco funciona. Es *Python 3.9.7.* Usé este código:

```
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()

operacional_1100 = book.active

maestro = pd.read_excel("2021 Gastos Ortodontik.xlsx", sheet_name="MAESTRO TR")

df_ordenar = maestro.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4]] 

df_ordenar2 = df_ordenar['Monto'].replace(' ', '')

escrito = pd.ExcelWriter('prueba.xlsx')

df_ordenar2.to_excel(escrito)

escrito.save()
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar como texto algunas filas de tu tabla y agregar la descripción de qué espacios necesitas y cuales no?